# How to find all the contiguous subsequence of an array is less than O(N^2) time complexity?

Tags: algorithms

I am unable to find product of every contiguous subsequence of an array in less than O(N^2) time complexity.

What actually i want to do is find the number of contagious subsequence whose product of elements is either odd or multiple of 4. The problem here is time i want an algorithm which can make it happen in O(N).

```
public class PrintAllSubArrays {

    public void printSubArrays(int [] arrA){

        int arrSize = arrA.length;
        //start point
        for (int startPoint = 0; startPoint <arrSize ; startPoint++) {
            //group sizes
            for (int grps = startPoint; grps <=arrSize ; grps++) {
                //if start point = 1 then
                //grp size = 1 , print 1
                //grp size = 2, print 1 2
                //grp size = 3, print 1 2 3 ans so on
                for (int j = startPoint ; j < grps ; j++) {
                    System.out.print(arrA[j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arrA = {1,2,3, 4};
        new PrintAllSubArrays().printSubArrays(arrA);
    }

}
```

---

This question is part of a problem from a finished programming contest: ["Squared Subsequences" (April 2020)](https://www.codechef.com/APRIL20B/problems/SQRDSUB)

Comment: Can you start by defining the problem and explaining your solution? This site is more focused on the ideas than the actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contiguous subsequence satisfies your conditions if either it consists only of odd elements, or it contains one number which is a multiple or 4, or it contains two numbers which are multiples of 2. This suggests computing the following quantities:

- $X$: Number of contiguous subsequences consisting only of odd elements.
- $Y$: Number of contiguous subsequences containing an even element.
- $Z$: Number of contiguous subsequences containing no element which is a multiple of 4, and exactly one even element which is not a multiple of 4.

You are interested in $X+Y-Z$.

To determine $X,Y$, it suffices to partition the elements into odd (O) and even (E). If your sequence is of the form
$$
O^{\ell_1} E O^{\ell_2} E \cdots O^{\ell_r} E O^{\ell_{r+1}},
$$
then
$$
X = \sum_{i=1}^{r+1} \binom{\ell_i+1}{2}, \\
Y = \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq r+1} (\ell_i+1) (\ell_j+1).
$$
In order to compute $Y$ quickly, note that
$$
2Y = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{r+1} (\ell_i+1)\right)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{r+1} (\ell_i+1)^2.
$$

In order to compute $Z$, we first separate our sequence by breaking at every element which is a multiple of 4. If $Z_j$ is the number of $Z$-type contiguous subsequences in the $j$th subsequence, then $Z = Z_j$. We can write the $j$th subsequence as
$$
O^{\ell_1} E O^{\ell_2} E \cdots O^{\ell_r} E O^{\ell_{r+1}},
$$
just as before. We then have
$$
Z_j = \sum_{i=1}^r (\ell_i+1) (\ell_{i+1}+1).
$$
In total, the algorithm runs in linear time.

Disclaimer: Verify that the formulas work – they might be slightly off, but the general idea should work.

Comment: Actually it is possible that we break our subsequence whenever the modulo is 2 and remove when the modulo is 0 and then subtract the subsequnce that are being made by them??

Comment: Many problems can be solved in several different ways. If you can show that your solution works, then it works. The fact that another solution also works makes no difference.

Comment: This is also a great example of an XY question - you need to solve X, and you think that in order to solve X, you need to solve Y. You _can't_ find all contiguous subsequences in less than O(n^2) because there are n^2/2 of them. But it turns out, nobody asked you to solve Y, and you don't _need_ it to solve the original problem X.